# Update Library in SAS

Tags: sas, union

I may or may not have a library named qa.my_library
I have a temp library (same columns, different data) in work.my_library_temp

My goal is to achieve this pseudo code

```
if qa.my_library doesn't exists
then qa.my_library = work.my_library_temp;
else qa.my_library = SQL UNION (qa.my_library, work.my_library_temp)
```

How would you write the code for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if a LIBRARY exists use the [LIBREF](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212077.htm) function. To determine if a DATA SET exists use the [EXIST](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/670.html) function.

Here is some sample code:

```
%Global LIBEXISTS DSNEXISTS;
Options source source2 notes symbolgen mlogic mprint ;

%Macro Check(Lib=,DSN=);
 %Let LIBEXISTS=0;
 /* Outside the DATA STEP, use %SYSFUNC */
 %IF %SYSFUNC(LIBREF(&LIB)) = 0 %THEN %Let LIBEXISTS=1; ;

 %Let DSNEXISTS=0;
 %IF %SYSFUNC(EXIST(&DSN)) > 0 %THEN %Let DSNEXISTS=1; ;

%Mend;

libname test 'c:\';
Data Test.Temp;
 Test="Test";
Run;

%Check(Lib=test,dsn=test.temp) ;

%Put LIB EXISTS? &libexists;
%Put DSN EXISTS? &dsnexists;

libname test clear;

%Check(Lib=test,dsn=test.temp) ;

%Put LIB EXISTS? &libexists;
%Put DSN EXISTS? &dsnexists;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for the concept of libraries is to avoid name collisions. What you ask would be unable to deal with such collision (i.e., a dataset with the same name in both libraries). If you can be certain that there will be no collision, than there is actually no reason for what you want: there is no fundamental difference between remembering (and parsing) a unique dataset name or a unique dataset name with its library.


Leaves only the situation where there can be collisions, but you have one library who has priority then. You can write something that gets somewhat close to what you want:

Using SASHELP library, identify every dataset in library A and B. Assuming that A takes priority: for every dataset in B which is not in A, run the following:

```
data A.dataset_from_B /view=A.dataset_from_B;
    set B.dataset_from_B;
run;
```

Again, it is not exactly the same, but probably serves your needs. But I would be really interested in knowing why you want this though.

Comment: I run a script that creates the temp library with a column timestamp that is the actual rundate of the script. I want to append the results of this script to the total results of all the executions over time of the script.